# How can implementation know if an input parameter is mutable?

Tags: java

For example, some method has the next implementation:

```
void setExcludedCategories(List<Long> excludedCategories) {
    if (excludedCategories.contains(1L)) {
        excludedCategories.remove(1L);
    }
}
```

And it's called in the next way:

```
setExcludedCategories(Array.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));
```

Of course, it will lead ot an exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException when it will try to remove item.

The question: how can I modify this code to be sure that the input parameter excludedCategories supports remove?

UPD:
Thanks for answers. Let's summarize results:

1. Always create new ArrayList from the input list to be sure it's mutable - a lot of useless memory would be used -> NO.
2. Catch the UnsupportedOperationException.
3. Specify in the JavaDoc that a caller mustn't pass an immutable list - anybody read the JavaDoc? When something doesn't work only :)
4. Don't use Arrays.asList() in a caller's code - that's an option, if you an owner of this code, but anyway you should know if this concrete method allows immutable or not (see 3).

It seems the second variant is the only way to resolve this problem.

Comment: Obviously I don't know what your code is doing besides the sample code you've posted, but would it be feasible for you to copy the data from the parameter and place it into a mutable List?

Comment: You don't need that `if` statement.  It's perfectly safe and legal to remove something from a Collection, even if it's not present in the Collection.

Comment: Yes, it's an obvious way to fix it, but it will lead to an additional memory usage. The best fix would be don't allow to pass immutable list at all. So I'm asking for possible ways how to do that.

Comment: @RomanProshin - Don't use `Arrays.asList()` which returns an instance of `Arrays$List` and NOT `java.util.ArrayList`. Pass a normal list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I modify this code to be sure that the input parameter excludedCategories supports remove?

In the general case, you can't.  Given an arbitrary class that implements the `List` API, you cannot tell (statically or dynamically) if the optional methods are supported.

You can use `instanceof` tests to check if the class of the list is *known* to implement the method or to not implement it.  For example `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` do, but `Collections.UnmodifiableList` does not.  The problem is that your code could encounter list classes that your tests don't cover.  (Especially if it is a library that is intended to be reusable in other peoples applications.)

You could also try to test the behavior of previously unknown classes; e.g. create a test instance, try a `remove` to see what happens, and record the behavior in a `Map<Class, Boolean>`.  There are two problems with this:

- You may not be able to (correctly) instantiate the list class to test it.
- The behavior could depend on how you instantiate the class (e.g. constructor parameters) or even on the nature of the element you are trying to remove ... though the latter is pushing the boundary of plausibility.

In fact, the only *completely reliable* approach is to call the method and catch the exception (if it is thrown) each and every time.

Answer (score 2):

In short, you can't know.  If an object implements an interface (such as `List`) you can't know if it will actually do what is expected for all of the methods.  For instance `Collections.unmodifiableList()` returns a `List` that throws `UnsupportedOperationException`.  It can't be filtered out via the method signature if you want to be able to get other `List` implementations.

The best you can do is to throw `IllegalArgumentException` for known subtypes that don't support what you want.  And catch `UnsupportedOperationException` for other types of cases.  But really you should javadoc your method with what is required and that it throws `IllegalArgumentException` in other cases.

Comment: The question here is not about exception handling. I think its the API which produces immutable list and hence the exceptoin on removal which is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Comment: Yes it is not about exception handling.  Which is why my answer said you can't know.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That depends somewhat on what you're trying to do. In your posted example for example you could just catch the `UnsupportedOperationException` and do something else instead.

This assumes that you can assume that non-mutable containers will throw that on every attempt to modify the container and will do so without side effects (that is they are indeed non-mutable).

In other cases where your code has other side effects than trying to modify the container you will have to make sure these doesn't happen before knowing that you can modify the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the exception in an utility class like in the example below (as others mentioned). Bad thing is you have to do insert/delete to test if there will be exception. You can not use instanceof since all [Collections.Unmodifiablexxx](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) classes have default access.

CollectionUtils:

```
import java.util.List;

public class CollectionUtils {

    public <T> boolean isUnmodifiableList(List<T> listToCheck) {

        T object = listToCheck.get(0);

        try {
            listToCheck.remove(object);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException unsupportedOperationException) {
            return true;
        }
        listToCheck.add(0, object);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    private static final CollectionUtils COLLECTION_UTILS = new CollectionUtils();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        setExcludedCategories(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L));


    }

    private static void setExcludedCategories(List<Long> excludedCategories) {
        if (excludedCategories.contains(1L)) {
            if(!COLLECTION_UTILS.<Long>isUnmodifiableList(excludedCategories)){
                excludedCategories.remove(1L);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Good idea! But i worry about performance of this solution: remove and then add item back - it should costs something.

Comment: @RomanProshin yes we dont know if linkedlist or arraylist will be tested so in any case performance affect. I also mentioned in answer. Hashcode and equals override is another story that all items can be removed as well but i think its out of topic:)

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(T... a)` returns the `List<java.util.Arrays.ArrayList<E>>` which is an immutable list. To get your code working just wrap the result with `java.util.ArrayList<T>` like shown below

```
setExcludedCategories(new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L)));
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but then I have to wrap input lists in **everywhere** method, because I don't know if somebody will pass an immutable list here. And at the same time it will lead to an overhead by memory - create new array list always even if this list is mutable.

Comment: When we talk about the consumers of the method. It totally depends on the implementation. If some peice of code is using the method you mentioned that should follow certain contract. In your case its that the list should be mutable. 

Speaking of what kind of object will be passed in other library, you should not be worried about because just because you defined a possiblity of interface does not mean you should support all implementation. Specially when you are doing a mutation in a list. Memory would not be a problem as you are creating a local variable for each list.

Comment: Sorry for writing it too late. It hit me that your contract can always handle exception so if an immutable collection is passed just catch the run time exception and handle it accordingly.

It also doesn't violate the coding principles as immutable list are exceptional cases and they are not the part of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Always create new ArrayList from the input list to be sure it's mutable - a lot of useless memory would be used -> NO.

Thats actually the preferred way to do things. "A lot of useless memory" isn't a lot in most practical situations, certainly not in your cited exampled.

And ignoring that, its the only *robust* and *inutitively* understood idiom.

The only workable alternative would be to explicitly change the name of your method (thus communicating its behavior better), form the example you show, name it "removeExcludedCategories" if its meant to modify the argument list (but not an objects state).

Otherwise if it is meant as a bulk-setter, you're out of luck, there is no commonly recognized naming idiom that clearly communicates that the argument collection is directly incorporated into the state of an object (its dangerous also because the objects state can then be altered without the object knowing about it).

Also, only marginally related, I would design not an exclusion *list*, but an exclusion *set*. Sets are conceptually better suited (no duplicates) and there are set implementations that have far better runtime complexity for the most commonly asked question: contains().